# Error Expected Identifier or '('

Tags: objective-c

I need help finding out why I am receiving this error? I am new at coding and trying to fix this problem.

```
if (pan.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    if (self.topLayer.frame.orgin.x <= 160) {
        [self animateLayerToPoint:0];
    }  else {
        [self animatelayerToPoint: VIEW_HIDDEN];
    }
}
```

This is where I got the error on line "if"

```
if (self.topLayer.frame.orgin.x <= 160)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 10):

You have a typo: `orgin` instead of `origin`.

Comment: ooh ok thank you it say also i have extraneous closing brave how do i fix that problem